# mysql duplicated my rows over night

Tags: mysql, duplication

Ok I know this might sound screwed up, but mysql sometime yesturday through an unexpected curball my way, which i have never come across before.

SO we have a database table called employees 
in that table you have records like

```
Russell
Smith
Sam
```

but all of a sudden i have

```
Russell
Russell
Smith
Smith
Smith
Sam
Sam
Sam
```

If anyone knows how to fix this without, downloading the full table and manually fixing it and re uploading that would be great

Comment: Not sure why that would happen, weird! Maybe talk to your webhost about it!

Comment: Are you executing a simple SQL? 'select * from table'

Comment: Cartesian join involving the employee table introduced sometime yesterday into the code?

Comment: Please show the `ID`'s for those records.

Answer (score 1):

If your table has an `id` column and you want to keep only the records with lowest `id` you can do

```
delete from employees 
where id not in 
(
   select * from 
   (
     select min(id) 
     from employees 
     group by name
   ) x
)
```

Comment: . . I thought about this.  But if the rows are being duplicated, wouldn't the id also be duplicated?  If so, this isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation:

(1) Create a new temporary table as:

```
create temporary table xxx as
    select distinct * from employees
```

(2) Truncate the original table

```
truncate table employees
```

(3) Insert the records back in

```
insert into employees
    select * from xxx
```

By truncating the table, you will be keeping almost all information associated with it -- security, triggers, constraints.  The one issue may be an auto-incremented primary key.  This may not work if you have one of those (but then again, you couldn't duplicate the records if there is a primary key).

Comment: You can also manually correct an auto-increment counter (`ALTER TABLE mytable AUTO_INCREMENT = 500`).